# Risk dominance in NE

Tags: game-theory, self-study

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea of risk dominance but I am not confident whether or not what I am thinking is correct.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 80, 80 | 80, 0 |
| B | 0, 80 | 100, 00 |

The solution says that the risk dominance here is (A, A), and explains that it is more costly to mistakenly think we are playing B than to mistakenly think we are playing A. Here's my thought process so far.

Player 1 would prefer to stick with A to get a payoff of 80, rather than going for B with a chance to get 100 but also with a chance to get nothing with 0. Same thing for player 2 - he also wants to stick with A to get a payoff of 80 rather than risking for 100 or nothing.

Now here comes this example, which is where I am truly confused.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 80, 80 | 0, 0 |
| B | 0, 0 | 100, 100 |

The solution says that the answer is (Bottom, Right), which is (100, 100). Here's my thought process for this example. Suppose we are player 1. We will be playing A and we think that player 2 is going for A too, but he ends up going for B. That means we are losing out for 80 - 0 = 80. Now suppose that we will play B and we think that player 2 is going for B too, but he goes for A. That means we are losing out for 100 - 0 = 100. This is symmetric for player 2 too. So losing out for 80 and 100...obviously, losing 80 sucks less than losing 100.

Is my thought process correct? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a generic symmetric $2\times2$ game as below:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
&A&B\\\hline
A&a,a & b,c \\\hline 
B&c,b & d,d \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ are distinct. Further suppose that $(A,A)$ and $(B,B)$ are pure strategy NEs. By definition, $(A,A)$ risk dominates $(B,B)$ if and only if
$$a-c>d-b\,, \tag{1}$$
and the direction of domination reverses with the inequality.

Now consider the statement

> it is more costly to mistakenly think we are playing $B$ than to mistakenly think we are playing $A$.

Suppose player 2 plays $A$, but player 1 *mistakenly* believes that player 2 is playing $B$. That erroneous belief would lead player 1 to play $B$, which causes player 1 to deviate from the equilibrium $(A,A)$ and entails a cost of $a-c$. Likewise, if player 1 mistakenly thinks that player 2 would play $A$ while the latter is playing $B$, the cost of deviating from the $(B,B)$ equilibrium would be $d-b$.

Plug in the numbers from your first example, the above statement corresponds to condition $(1)$, namely,
$$a-c=80-0>100-80=d-b$$
thus making $(A,A)$ the risk dominant NE.

In the second example, the numbers turn out to be
$$a-c=80-0<100-0=d-b$$
which reverses the inequality in $(1)$, making $(B,B)$ risk dominant. The interpretation is symmetric to the one given for the first example:

> it is more costly to mistakenly think we are playing $A$ than to mistakenly think we are playing $B$.